# MCMC acceptance rate with discrete but noisy function

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I have a question regarding the acceptance rate of MCMC sampling (I am using an implementation of the Goodman and Weare 2010 algorithm) in the special case that the output of my model has a considerable amount of randomness / noise. Specifically, the model consists in a variant of a Wiener process for which no analytical solution exists, and the fit (logL) therefore depends not only on the parameters, but also on the simulated random walk, which obviously varies when parameters are even only changed by a tiny amount. Therefore, even very similar parameters can vary to a certain degree wrt the logL returned. Now I am pretty sure that this in general is no problem for MCMC sampling, but with increasing sampling I notice that the acceptance rate drops considerably, until as low as 2-3%. I think what happens is that the accepted proposals are more and more "selected" due to variance in the random numbers and, thus, new proposals need to not only be somewhat reasonable parameters, but also in a sense draw well from the random noise. Does that make sense at all? And if so, does someone know a way to deal with this?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is your estimator of the likelihood (not log likelihood) unbiased?
If not, you should be aware that your MCMC chain is going to be (possibly heavily) biased.
Also, how many parameters does your model have?
My (limited) experience with G&W is that it's not that great.

Comment: With estimator of the likelihood you mean the loss function? I am using QMLE (https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03196299) to estimate parameters of models of response time distributions, and while this is not an unbiased estimator, it is only slightly biased with enough data. The model has 9 parameters, but the effect is very similar if I fix some parameters.

Comment: I don't know what QMLE does. I mean whether the estimator of the likelihood (not log likelihood) for a given parameter vector is unbiased -- not whether the parameter estimates are unbiased (which seems what you're answer is about), it's a completely different thing.

Comment: QMLE is used to estimate the likelihood of a parameter vector and itself should be relatively unbiased. Not sure I get what you mean with "not log likelihood"? Could you explain a bit more? :)

Comment: The estimator of the log likelihood is not the same thing as the estimator of the likelihood (there is a nonlinear transformation between the two). MCMC to be correct requires an unbiased estimator of the likelihood. See [here](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/the-pseudo-marginal-approach-to-exact-approximate-mcmc-algorithms/). That aside, the variance of your estimator will heavily affect the stickiness of MCMC chains. Try and reduce the variance of your estimator.